# Can I declare my table in set query?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Can I declare a table in set query of SQL:

```
SET @ParmDefinition = '@TempTable table (ID int, Name varchar(20))'
```

Please let us know your response on above question....

Please help me.

Comment: No i want to create a table from back end..

Comment: so what your requirement is.?

Comment: No i want to create a table from back end..

Comment: I want to define table in SET query...Only i want to know is it possible to create table in SET query....

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot use a table variable in a dynamic SQL statement. You can however use a local or global table (#MyTable) within dynamic SQL - but when using dynamic SQL please be mindful of the security concerns like SQL Injection.